# Ruby taking the last vowel from a word problem

Tags: ruby

I've been stressing out a lot about a problem I feel like I should be getting but don't know why it's not working.

Basically a method that takes a word and returns a word without the last vowel.

My code was:

```
def lastvowel(word)
    vowels = "aeiou"

    if vowels.include? (word)
        word.reverse.sub(/[aeiou]/, "").reverse
    else
        return word 
    end


end
```

the problem was that the vowels.include? (word) was not working? but I feel like it should be working? Maybe I'm thinking something else. 
So instead I made it like this:

```
def lastvowel(word)
    vowel = "aeiou"

    word.each_char do |x|
        if vowel.include?(x) 
        return word.reverse.sub(/[aeiou]/, "").reverse
        end
    end
return word

end
```

Is my understanding of the .include? method not correct? Any help would be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vowels.include? (word)` would test e.g. if the word is found in the string `"aeiou"`. First of all, you likely wanted to test the reverse, whether vowels are in the word, not if the word is in the vowels; secondly, no word in English language has `"aeiou"` as its substring (the closest AFAIK are `"leguleious"`, `"epigaeous"`, `"glutaeous"` and `"paeounlae"`, with one of the vowels missing).

What you want is to know if *any* of the vowels is included in the word; the shortest way to write that is `vowels.any? { |vowel| word.include?(vowel) }`. The check is not really necessary, if there are no vowels in the word you'd just be doing some unnecessary reversals.

Finally, you can do everything in just one `sub`, without reversals, and no tests:

```
word.sub(/[aeiou](?!.*?[aeiou])/, "")
```

("a vowel not followed by stuff and another vowel")

Comment: Can the lazy qualifier be dropped from `(?!.*?[aeiou])` (i.e., `(?!.*[aeiou])`)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, in this case it will only affect the execution strategy, but not the result. i.e. different shapes of "word" will be more, or less efficient. You can test on regex101 which reports "number of steps". Neither variant is inherently better or worse, just better or worse for a particular input. Though... I also quite like Sergio's greedy group way.

Comment: @Amadan thank you for the help! I was trying to avoid using regex since I didn't get there yet in learning Ruby but it seems lot of these problems can be more simply solved with regex! So i'll study that more. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You could define `String#lastvowel`:

```
class String
  def lastvowel
    sub(/(.*)[aeiou](.*)/,'\1\2')
  end
end
```

and use like this:

```
"something".lastvowel
=> "somethng"
```

Comment: It is classy like your bio :)

Answer (score 1):

```
"problematic".sub(/[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*\z)/i, '')
  #=> "problematc"

"HELLO".sub(/[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*\z)/i, '')
  #=> "HELL"

"sly".sub(/[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*\z)/i, '')
  #=> "sly"
```

See [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-sub).

The regular expression reads, "match any vowel (`[aeiou]`) followed by zero or more (`*`) characters other than vowels (`[^aeiou]`), followed by the end of the string (`\z`), the matches being case indifferent (`/i`)".

`[aeiou]` is a *character class*, meaning exactly one of its contents is to be matched.

`(?=[^aeiou]*\z)` is a *positive lookahead* (signified by `?=`).

`[^aeiou]` is also a character class, but the carat (`^`) in the first position means that exactly one character other than the characters that follow `^` is to be matched. Here that means a consonant.

Another way is to use the method [String#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-rindex):

```
str = "problematic"
idx = str.rindex(/[aeiou]/i)
idx ? (str[0,idx]+str[idx+1..-1]) : str
  #=> "problematc"
```

```
str = "A"
idx = str.rindex(/[aeiou]/i)
idx ? (str[0,idx]+str[idx+1..-1]) : str
  #=> ""
```